# select sql с ошибкой 1054

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь выбрать все товары из таблицы "sales" и подцепить из таблицы "nomenclature_list" название бренда, у обеих таблиц есть одинаковое поле nmId, и я делаю выборку сравнивая по нему. Я делал запрос с LEFT JOIN и все работало, но задваивалась выдача, пытаюсь переписать запрос и получаю ошибку #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'nomenclature_list.brand' в 'field list'
Хотя данный столбец в таблице существует. Подскажите в чем проблема пожалуйста, вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT sales.*, 
       nomenclature_list.brand AS "nBrand" 
FROM sales 
WHERE sales.nmId = nomenclature_list.nmId 
  AND sales.date BETWEEN '2023-08-11' AND '2023-09-11T23:59:59' 
  AND sales.usr_id = '2' 
ORDER BY sales.date DESC
```

Comment: У вас `FROM sales` указана только одна таблица. Если при join у вас дублируются записи, значит в одной из таблиц по ключу есть дубли

Comment: Да, так и есть, одинаковый столбец brand, но в SELECT я заменяю его на nBrand

Comment: у вас текущий запрос из одной таблицы данные выбирает и ничего не знает про таблицу `nomenclature_list`. Верните джойн и либо решите проблему с дублями в этой таблице `nomenclature_list` (если поле это предполагаемый ключ), либо добавьте нужные условия джойна, чтобы исключить дубли.

Comment: Сделал запрос без JOIN LEFT и он так же задваивается:

SELECT sales.*, nomenclature_list.brand AS nBrand 
FROM sales, nomenclature_list
WHERE sales.nmId = nomenclature_list.nmId AND sales.date BETWEEN '2023-08-11' AND '2023-09-11T23:59:59' AND sales.usr_id = '2' 
ORDER BY sales.date DESC